# We have an urn with n balls, numbered from 1 to n. Whats the chance of getting the ball with number k exactly after k-1 draws?

Tags: statistics, probability

So, the problem is:

We have an urn with **N** balls, each numbered from 1 to n.

We keep drawing without putting back, and the question is whats the chance that one of the balls with number **k** (k can be anything) will be drawn exactly after **k-1** draws?

Comment: This question is off-topic since it has nothing to do with programming

Comment: I simulated it, but i want to check the real result so i can compare it...

Comment: Still off-topic since you're just looking for the answer to that particular math problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

should be 1/n.

Approach 1: You only care about the kth draw, which must be a precise ball. Odds of that are 1/n, the other draws are free choices otherwise.

Approach 2: (grind the raw probability)

The first (k-1) draws each have probability (n-i)/(n-i+1), which when multiplied reduces to (n-k+1)/n

The kth draw probability is 1/(n-k+1)

(n-k+1)/n * 1/(n-k+1) = 1/n